# Twitter API question

Tags: c#, twitter

I would like to make my app post status update to the users' account? (like wefollow.com) do you know which twitter api function is that?

and also I would like to use sign in with twitter.
found this but they don't have any code examples
http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Sign-in-with-Twitter

Comment: What language do you want to write this with?

Comment: Please let us know what language you will be using and what platform.

Answer (score 3):

The [update](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses%C2%A0update) method

Answer (score 1):

You need `Update` method, and you can use [twitterizer](http://code.google.com/p/twitterizer/) to call twitter API from .NET, some examples [here](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/twitter-aspnet) at .NET Zone.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this http://jdp.github.com/twitterlibphp/ to work with twitter, it's easy. I suggest it if you're using PHP.

Comment: The linked library uses username/password authentication which will be deprecated fairly soon. Oauth should be used instead. For PHP, try Abraham Williams' http://github.com/jdp/twitterlibphp.

Comment: where did you see that it will be deprecated soon?

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a somewhat recent article on Twitter OAuth with C#](http://www.dieinahole.com/2009/05/18/update-twitter-oauth-in-c/). I don't do C#, so I can't vouch for how good it is, but should be a good start.

Comment: I would point out that most of the .NET examples seem to be using Basic Auth, and you should really be looking at OAuth.